# "I couldn't find XXX" and "I didn't find XXX" which is better?

Tags: word-usage

We communicate via email. He told me to get something under an address. But I can't find it under that location.

How would I say?

> I didn't find it.

-

> I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3):

**"I couldn't find it"** is more appropriate for your case, I think.

**"I didn't find it"** implies that you *chose* not to find it. **"I couldn't find it"** tells the listener that you tried, but failed.

Comment: +1 Pretty spot on !